# Exibir nome do usuário logado

Tags: php, html

Exemplo em código arquivo **index.php**:

```
<header>

        <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
        <label for="btn-menu" class="icon-menu"></label>
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php"><span class="icon-home"></span>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-info"></span>Sobre</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-calendar"></span>Agendamento</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

                <button type="button" class="cadastro btn-login"><a href="login-cadastro.php">Login</a></button>
                <button type="button" class="cadastro btn-cadastro"><a href="login-cadastro.php">Cadastre-se</a></button>
        </header>
```

Quando o usuário fazer o login, queria que as opções Login e Cadastre-se sumisse, e no lugar dessas opções aparecer o nome de quem logou.

estava pensando em replicar o código do **index.php** para o  **index-logado.php**(exemplo), e abrir uma sessão nesse novo código, colocando o nome dele lá.

Exemplo em código arquivo **index-logado.php**:

```
session_start();
    <header>

            <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
            <label for="btn-menu" class="icon-menu"></label>
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index-logado.php"><span class="icon-home"></span>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-info"></span>Sobre</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-calendar"></span>Agendamento</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            echo "BEM-VINDO". $_SESSION['nome-usuario'];

            </header>
```

Não sei se essa é uma maneira correta, é a única que eu pensei, e sei até o momento.

se tivesse uma condição que alterasse diretamente no index.php seria a solução mais prática ao meu ver, porém se existe, eu n tenho o conhecimento dela ainda.

**TENTATIVA N°1:**

```
<?php session_start(); 
require_once("Valida.php");
?>

<header>

        <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
        <label for="btn-menu" class="icon-menu"></label>
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php"><span class="icon-home"></span>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-info"></span>Sobre</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-calendar"></span>Agendamento</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
                <?php 
                    if ($v->getValida()) {
                ?>
                    <span><?php echo "Bem-vindo ".$_SESSION['email'];  ?></span>


                <?php}else{?>


                <button type="button" class="cadastro btn-login"><a href="login-cadastro.php">Login</a></button>
                <button type="button" class="cadastro btn-cadastro"><a href="login-cadastro.php">Cadastre-se</a></button>

                <?php } ?>


        </header>
```

**Arquivo Valida.php**

```
<?php 

 class Valida{


    private $valida;

    function getValida(){
        return $this->valida;
    }

    function setValida($valida){
        $this->valida = $valida;
    }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Você pode fazer através de if e else para verificar se a $_SESSION['nome-usuario'] está vazio ou setado e então exibir o nome do usuário caso a $_Session for verdadeira, podendo fazer tudo na mesma página, sem a necessidade de você replicar o código

Comment: Saul da Silva Rolim, já foi autenticado o usuário.
vou dar o passo a passo 

1° O usuario loga em login.php  
2° Autentica em Autenticar.php  
3° Redireciona de Autenticar.php, para index.php  

Só que nesse index eu queria saber, se tem como fazer uma condição que altera o arquivo index.php pra colocar o SESSION, ou se é feito da maneira que fiz acima, e se da pra alterar o arquivo, como isso é feito.

Comment: Entendi o que você quis dizer Saul da Silva Rolim, não estava enxergando essa possibilidade de condição junto ao html, Obrigado.

Comment: você conseguiu fazer?

Comment: ainda não, mais já sei aonde é o problema, só to tentando descobrir como arruma-lo

Comment: Não estou conseguindo fazer ainda, editei o post, coloquei os arquivos que estou tentando. o getValida() chega no arquivo de validação, exibe, mais no arquivo de cabecalho ele não exibe nada. //// Outra coisa, além de não chegar, minha condição exibe os 2, tanto os botoes como o bem-vindo, se eu inverter a condição ela retira os 2(botão e bem vindo)

Comment: Uma sessão somente deixará de existir se você a destruiu ou ela expirar. Logo basta verificar se a variavel da sessão está setada e exibir a informação (partindo do principio que você armazenou o nome do usuario na sessão)

Comment: Resolvi o problema, meu else estava junto a tag <?php}else{?>

Answer (score 1):

Bom uma maneira fácil seria "IFar" uma vez que está usando o PHP, segue abaixo a sugestão : (trocar vars e tags pelas suas)

```
<header>
  <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
  <label for="btn-menu" class="icon-menu"></label>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php"><span class="icon-home"></span>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-info"></span>Sobre</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-calendar"></span>Agendamento</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <?php if ($usuario_status == 'LOGADO') { ?>
    <span><?php echo $usuario_nome;?></span>
  <?php } else { ?>
    <button type="button" class="cadastro btn-login"><a href="login-cadastro.php">Login</a></button>
    <button type="button" class="cadastro btn-cadastro"><a href="login-cadastro.php">Cadastre-se</a></button>
   <?php } ?>
</header>
```

Comment: Interessante, não pensei nessa solução, vou testar aqui e dou o feedback, valeu carlosgaddini. ^^

Comment: Bom os PHPuristas talvez não vão gostar da minha sugestão, mas ela é de fácil compreensão que foi meu objetivo. Qualquer coisa pergunte novamente.

Comment: estou com dificuldade pra fazer o valor da validação, chegar na minha condição do IF, editei o post e coloquei o que estou fazendo, por algum motivo o valor que eu passo não esta chegando na minha condição IF  //// Outra coisa, além de não chegar, minha condição exibe os 2, tanto os botoes como o bem-vindo, se eu inverter a condição ela retira os 2(botão e bem vindo)

Comment: Resolvi o problema.

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer é criar dois tipos diferentes de "menu" um para quando está conectado e outro  para quando é um visitante não conectado.

Por exemplo:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['nome-usuario'])){
  include('conectado/menu.php');
}else{
  include('desconectado/menu.php');
}
```

Comment: meu arquivo de validação já faz o redirecionamento, o problema é que quando redireciona pra index.php aparece o nome do usuario logado, e os botões de login e cadastro, quero que quando ele fizer login, os botões saem.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Tenho esse arquivo (`index.php`) onde quero mostrar o nome do usuário logado na tela apos seu login, porem esta dando um erro de variável indefinida ( `$_SESSION`).

**Observação:** desconsiderar a linha do ultimo `div=principal`

```
</head>
<body>
        <?php 
            include('includes/topoemenu.php');
            require_once('includes/db.php');

                $usuario   = $_SESSION['usuarioSession'];
                $senha     = $_SESSION['senhaSession'];

                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM syslogin WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'");

                    while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                        $usuario = $linha['usuario'];
                        $senha   = $linha['senha'];
                        }
         ?>
        <div class="bemvindo">Bem Vindo! <strong><?php echo $usuario;?></strong> | Hoje é: <?php echo date('d/m/Y');?></div><!--Bem Vindo-->

        <div id="principal">
                    <h3>Bem Vindo(a).</h3><br /><br />
                    <img src="css/img/logo1.jpg" alt="logo" />
        </div> <!-- Fim da div#principal -->

        <?php include('includes/fimerodape.php'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Por favor onde estou errando?

Comment: Seja bem vindo, considere fazer um [tour] para tirar o melhor proveito do site. Você usou o campo de resposta para perguntar... Boa Sorte

Answer (score -3):

para resolver seu problema você só precisa colocar acima de todo o HTML o  session_start() dentro da tag php que já deve funcionar.